gdb not able to view source of x86_64 asm programs
Update
As suggested by Michael Petch, switching to nasm version 2.16.01 fixed my problem.
Original Post
I use a fresh install of Ubuntu 22.04, nasm 2.15.05 and gdb 12.1.
Is there anything that has to be done different to be able see the source when debugging x64-Assembly?
The same steps that worked for x86-Assembly do not work for x64-Assembly.
Here is a short breakdown:
x86/helloWorld.asm
section .data
msg:     db     'Hello, World!',0       ; define string as label

section .text
global start                            ; must be declared for linker

start:                                  ; entry point
        mov     eax, 4                  ; system call number (sys_write)
        mov     ebx, 1                  ; file descriptor (stdout)
        mov     ecx, msg                ; message
        mov     edx, 13                 ; message length
        int     0x80                    ; call kernel

        mov     eax, 1                  ; system call number (sys_exit)
        int     0x80                    ; call kernel

I assemble and link that using following commands:
nasm -f elf32 -g -F dwarf helloWorld.asm
ld -m elf_i386 -e start -o helloWorld helloWorld.o
I start gdb: gdb helloWorld
In gdb I set a breakpoint:
(gdb) break helloWorld.asm:9
Breakpoint 1 at 0x8049000: file helloWorld.asm, line 9.
I use lay n to get to the layout that is a split of regs/src on top and cmd at bottom.
As expected, regs is unavailable and in src is the content of helloWorld.asm.
Nice.
x64/helloWorld.asm
section .data
msg:     db     'Hello, World!',0       ; define string as label

section .bss

section .text
global start                            ; must be declared for linker

start:                                  ; entry point
        mov     rax, 1                  ; system call number (sys_write)
        mov     rdi, 1                  ; file descriptor (stdout)
        mov     rsi, msg                ; message
        mov     rdx, 13                 ; message length
        syscall                         ; call kernel

        mov     rax, 60                 ; system call number (sys_exit)
        mov     rdi, 0                  ; 0 = success exit code
        syscall                         ; call kernel

I assemble and link that using following commands:
nasm -f elf64 -g -F dwarf helloWorld.asm
ld -m elf_x86_64 -e start -o helloWorld helloWorld.o
I start gdb: gdb helloWorld
In gdb I set a breakpoint:
(gdb) break helloWorld.asm:9
No line 9 in file "helloWorld.asm".
Make breakpoint pending on future shared library load? (y or [n])
I use lay n to get to the layout that is a split of regs/src on top and cmd at bottom.
Regs is unavailable and [ No Source Available ].
When I enter (gdb) list, the source becomes available until the next step I do in the program.
Architecture seems to be fine as well:
(gdb) show architecture
The target architecture is set to "auto" (currently "i386:x86-64").
So why does gdb tell me that my source file is a future shared library and why does the source view not work properly?
What can I do to fix that?
I already tried:

Using a fresh install of gdb and Linux
Checked if sources are available to gdb when debugging x64 (they are; helloWorld and helloWorld.asm)
Set the file manually (changed nothing)

I expected:

To be able to debug without any inconveniences


Works here. Although I don't have your exact versions, I tried with both older and newer nasm and gdb. Note that line 9 is a label. My gdb version automatically puts the breakpoint on line 10 which is the one that actually has code. Try using line 10.

Putting the breakpoint into line 10 has the same result. Using (gdb) break start works but its still inconvenient not to have the src view working correctly.
I guess I'll try on a different system later.

It's very unlikely that you “fucked up gdb.”  A normal user cannot modify the files of a program installed via package management.

Get a newer version of NASM (easily built from source) that is at least 2.16.01 or later. There was a recent NASM bug fix to deal with a long standing bug. I believe what you are seeing is related to this other question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72694342/gdb-does-not-load-source-lines-from-nasm
